# CakePHP1.3 - Core.php - Is there a way to set debug to 2 if admin else 0

Tags: cakephp, authentication

All,

Is there a way to include Auth or any other Controller in core.php to check if the logged in user is admin. If it is set debug to 2 or else set it to 0.

Is that even possible or advisable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a `beforeFilter` method in your `AppController` and check there whether the user is an admin. If it is an admin, you change the `debug` value, else you use the value defined in `core.php`. Something like:

```
// app/app_controller.php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if (HERE_COMES_THE_ADMIN_CHECK) {
            Configure::write('debug', 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I thought it was working when I had this going, however, I forgot to change the Core.php debug to 0. Anyway, I plug this in exactly as in your answer but it does not work... pls let me know if I need anything else